# Ubuntu MATE raspberry pi 2 start screen problem

Tags: raspberrypi, ubuntu-mate

I have problem when I trying to use "ubuntu mate" on raspberry pi. You can see it on [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uK3zp.jpg).

Also I connecting to raspberrypi by PuTTY, and it works well.

What to do?